# "Post Catalyst Sensor Open Test" meaning

Tags: chevrolet, o2-sensor, dtc, cobalt, evap

('07 Cobalt LS, 2.2L Ecotec)

In this car's 'mode 6' OBD2 data, there is a GM-defined item, "Post Catalyst Sensor Open Test" (Test ID 8A).  [This page](https://www.aa1car.com/library/2005/mode06_gm_canvehicles.pdf) shows it as a count.  My scan tool also shows it having an accompanying "Maximum" (480).  Whenever the count exceeds this Max, the test is marked as "Failed"; otherwise, it can be "Pass", or (occasionally) "Incomplete".  The count seems to be reset to 0 at startup.

Over ~150 trips I've looked at, this count has ranged from 0 to 800.  If over 480, it's flagged as "Failed".  I have replace the sensor in question, to no effect.

Anyway, questions

- What triggers the count?  Is it literally an "open" circuit, loss of continuity?
- Is it testing the O2 sensor's heater, or the sensor itself?
- What interval are the counts accumulated over?
- Can a "failed" status lead to a CEL/MIL?  (I've had no CEL codes explicitly indicating an Oxygen Sensor failure.)
- Can a "failed" status = without a CEL - prevent the EVAP test from running?

Answer (score 0):

Open generally means that the circuit is open, so a loss of continuity. If you have replaced the sensor then it's probably an electrical problem in the wiring. It could be a problem in the ECU itself but it's more likely something in the connector or the wiring loom. I'd start by checking the connector for faults and giving it a good clean, then work your way up to see if there's chafing or some other visible problem.

Open heater circuits do have a separate diagnostic code (P0135), whether GM uses that code or lumps continuity together with the sensor I don't know. I'd assume they don't for now.  The troubleshooting is the same process anyhow.